# bash script to compare 2 files and update where needed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to update File1.conf with text from File2.conf using a bash script.

~/.group/File1.conf

```
group b = bill john
group a = bill amy john
```

./File2.conf

```
group b = bill amy cara mike joe
group c = bill steven mike larry
```

Resulting in ~/.group/File1.conf to look like

```
group b = bill amy cara mike joe
group a = bill amy john
group c = bill steven mike larry
```

I've been looking at `awk` and `sed` but can't seem to get the outputs correct. The only constant is the `group $ =` and the spacing.

Comment: What's the exact logic? Why is the `group b` line from File2.conf preferred over the `group b` line from File1.conf? What's the logic behind this line ordering?

Comment: And also, is the order important?

Comment: Line order is not important. I just wanted to show that the lines could be in any order. As long as each group is on its own line then they can be in any order.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write this awk:

```
awk -F= 'NR == FNR {seen[$1]; print; next} !($1 in seen)' File{2,1}.conf
```

To save the output back to File1.conf, either

1. use a temp file:

   ```
   t=$(mktemp)
   awk '...' File{2,1}.conf > "$t" && mv "$t" File1.conf
   ```
2. install `moreutils` package and use `sponge`

   ```
   awk '...' File{2,1}.conf | sponge File1.conf
   ```

Comment: Thank you. This worked just as expected. I ended up going with the temp files option as I am trying to keep dependencies to a minimum but I will look into sponge as well, as I have seen it used else ware.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this `sort`:

```
$ sort -t'=' -uk1,1 file2 file1
group a = bill amy john
group b = bill amy cara mike joe
group c = bill steven mike larry
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Ive never used sort before. This worked as expected. Ill have to look into seeing where this might help in more of the projects I am working on.